# Java8 Stream - use filter collect foreach in single line

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Is't possible to use filter(),collect() and foreach() in single statement instead of multiple statements?

I have a map and need to filter based on some condition and set some values to the content and return the map. My current looks like below, but i want all 3 in single statement.

Map inputMap (contains all info)

```
Map<String, Person> returnMap; 
            returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(p ->  p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

            returnMap.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
                Person person= entry.getValue();                
                person.setAction("update");
                person.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
            });
```

can this be converted to,

```
  Map<String, Person> returnMap; 
                returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p ->  p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())) 
 .forEach((entry) -> {
                    Person person= entry.getValue();                
                    person.setAction("update");
                    person.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
                });
```

(this code doesn't work)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no sense in insisting on doing it with one operation. Regardless of how you write it down, these *are* two operations.

But one thing you should consider, is, that there are more ways than `entrySet().stream()` to process all elements:

```
Map<String, Person> returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p ->  p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

returnMap.values().forEach(person -> {          
    person.setAction("update");
    person.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
});
```

If you still insist on making it look like a single operation, you can do it this way:

```
Map<String, Person> returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p ->  p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()),
        tmp -> {
            tmp.values().forEach(person -> {          
                person.setAction("update");
                person.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
            });
            return tmp;
        })
    );
```

This is syntactically a single statement, still, it does exactly the same as the former variant.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that `forEach` does not return an object so you have to handle it different. You can do it this way:

```
Map<String, Person> returnMap = new HashMap<>(); 
map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(p ->  p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
              .forEach((entry) -> {
                    Person person = entry.getValue();                
                    person.setAction("update");
                    person.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
                    returnMap.put(entry.getKey(), person);
                });
```

Comment: like this approach

Comment: This is a solution, not without irony, as it still consist of two statements. And of course, it is not compatible with parallel streams.

Comment: Hey,This answer perfectly fit the use-case until n unless you are not manipulating the object inside foreach block. To add more, if we do some manipulation inside foreach then all object are mutually shareable, which results in racing condition and mismatched outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the need to separate it into two steps as has been suggested.  It seems like the transformation could be done before the terminal operation, like this:

```
returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
                .map(e -> {
                    Person p = e.getValue();
                    p.setAction("update");
                    p.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
                    return e;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If you're squeamish about side effects to the `Map.Entry` being streamed, you could return a new `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` with the updated `Person` as its value, but none of the solutions so far is free of side-effects, since the values in the original Map are being modified. Regardless, here is the variation:

```
returnMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue().getCourse() == 123)
                .map(e -> {
                    Person p = e.getValue();
                    p.setAction("update");
                    p.setLastUpdatedTime(new Date());
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), p);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: The main concern is *interference*. The side effect of modifying the `Person` instances is unavoidable, as that’s the desired operation. Problems may occur, when the setter methods of different person instances somehow interact or when a particular instance occurs multiple times. Otherwise, you could even use `peek` here, which would be more concise than `map`. Rewrapping the entry in another entry doesn’t change whether the modification of the `Person` instance has interference or not, so it’s unnecessary.